# pythoninterpreter import error

Tags: java, python, jython

I have problem with importing package in python module.
That's what I do:

```
from mega.mega import Mega
if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Mega()
```

and from java I run:

```
interpreter.execfile("api.py");
```

But I still get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mega
```

In mega folder I have mega.py file and `__init__.py` file to mark this folder as package.

---

Now I get:

```
from mega.mega import Mega
SyntaxError: ("'import *' not allowed with 'from .'", ...path...
```

Comment: Is the `mega` folder somewhere on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: no but it is in the same folder as api.py

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add the parent directory of `mega` to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os

PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PATH)

from mega.mega import Mega
```

`__file__` is the filename of the `api.py` module (can be relative).

Comment: @donatello: That sounds like an error somewhere completely different. Are you using `from . import *` somewhere in `mega/__init__.py`?

Comment: No, I use this mega.py https://github.com/richardasaurus/mega.py/tree/master/mega

Comment: I know what's wrong, there was from .errors import blabla in mega.py, so I deleted dots and it seems to be ok

Comment: @donatello: those are relative imports which should work; sounds like you are trying to run this with an older python version instead.

Comment: It may be, I have used this files in clean CPython and were ok, but now I'm trying to use them in Jython from java so it might be the cause

Comment: @donatello: Right, Jython is a few ticks behind in language support. Use CPython 2.5 instead to test your code, or upgrade Jython to the new 2.7 beta.